# How to sort a Python List with a runtime defined amount of priorities

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I want to find a way in python to sort tuples prioritizing the lowest index elements. Is this possible in python? I'm overgeneralizing a different problem I have with sorting a list with priorities over values that I don't know before hand. 
For example, if I know the length of my tuple I could do this

```
sorted(myList, key=lambda n: (n[0],n[1]))
```

here I know that myList is made up of tuples with 2 elements, but I had to hard code it. Can I generalize this to sort based on priority for a tuple with x elements? Here's a pseudo code idea in python,

```
sorted(myList, key=lambda n: n[i] for i in range(len(n)))
```

Comment: `lambda n: tuple(n)`?

Comment: Simply define `item_priority(item)` function and write whatever code you want, just so it return a priority value to each item and then use `sorted(myList, key=item_priority)`.

Comment: @Nf4r I'm confused on what item_priority() would look like

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` does this by default; you don't even need a `key` argument.

```
>>> k = [(0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)]
>>> sorted(k)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: does it do this for mutable objects too like lists?

Comment: @JoshuaSegal I would suggest to check it yourself. Would be faster than waiting for the actual answer. But yes. It does.